# Biber entry for newspaper article in Windy City

Tags: biblatex, windycity

How do I cite a newspaper article in Chicago author-date style using Biber and Windy City?

I have the following entry in my `refs.bib` file:

```
@article{intlrankingsandconflicts,
    author = {Scott Jaschik},
    title = {International Rankings and Conflicts of Interest},
    journal = {Inside Higher Ed},
    issue = {May 3},
    year = {2021},
    url={https://www.insidehighered.com/admissions/article/2021/05/03/international-rankings-and-conflicts-interest}
}
```

And the following in the header of my `.tex` file:

```
\usepackage[reflist=true,style=windycity]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
```

Compiling the document with Biber then PDFLaTeX produces the following bibliography:

> Jaschik, Scott. 2021. “International Rankings and Conflicts of Interest.” *Inside Higher Ed,* May
> 3 2021. `https://www.insidehighered.com/admissions/article/2021/05/03/international-rankings-and-conflicts-interest`.

Note the missing comma between "May 3" and "2021." The correct style is

> Jaschik, Scott. 2021. “International Rankings and Conflicts of Interest.” *Inside Higher Ed,* May 3, 2021. `https://www.insidehighered.com/admissions/article/2021/05/03/international-rankings-and-conflicts-interest`.

as described [on the CMOS website here](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide/citation-guide-2.html#cg-news).

Answer (score 1):

`windycity` has an [extensive documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/windycity/doc/windycity.pdf) and an [extensive example `.bib` file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/windycity/doc/windycity.bib).

Newspaper articles are discussed in §14.191 *Basic citation format for newspaper articles* and the relevant `.bib` entries are [in ll. 2131-2159 of `windycity.bib`](https://github.com/brianchase/windycity/blob/429a9fd96639a7921b76056406638440c28e903e/doc/windycity.bib#L2131-L2159). Based on that we can come up with the following entry

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=windycity]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{intlrankingsandconflicts,
  author  = {Scott Jaschik},
  title   = {International Rankings and Conflicts of Interest},
  journal = {Inside Higher Ed},
  date    = {2021-05-03},
  url     = {https://www.insidehighered.com/admissions/article/2021/05/03/international-rankings-and-conflicts-interest},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,intlrankingsandconflicts}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Jaschik, Scott. “International Rankings and Conflicts of Interest.” Inside Higher Ed, May 3, 2021. https://www.insidehighered.com/admissions/article/2021/05/03/international-rankings-and-conflicts-interest.]

The only change was to use the `date` field for the date instead of piecing things together with `year` and `issue`.

Comment: Please don't confuse "extensive documentation" with "easily navigable" documentation! Ctrl+Fing "newspaper" in the 120-page [Windy City user manual](https://mirror.yongbok.net/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/windycity/doc/windycity.pdf) yields lots of discussion of the CMOS style, but none of how to implement it in Biber. I wasn't aware of the sample `.bib` file at all--thank you for directing me to it.

Comment: @Max Some tricks are useful: I gave up and just searched for "New York Times" and "Washington Post" thinking that those two newspapers might be go-to examples. Luckily there was a Washington Post article.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder about the voting behaviour on this site. Two votes for a comment saying I Ctrl+F'd for "Washington Post" to find an example, but no votes for the answer explaining what to do and resolving the problem?